# React data do not go to child component after fetch

Tags: javascript

I'm having a problem with the function `fetch`. I'm trying to send just a number for example "1", and I have access to this data in all child components, but after calling `fetch`, I'm no longer able to access this data.

App.jsx:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './App.css';
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch'
import Header from './Header'
import Content from './Content'
import Footer from './Footer'


class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)

      this.state = {
        stripdata: null
      }
    }
    componentWillMount() {
        fetch(`http://localhost:3000/data/info.json`)
              .then(results => results.json())
              .then(data => {
                this.setState({
                    stripdata: data
                })
                // console.log(this.state.stripdata)
              })
              .catch(err => {
                console.log("Didn't connect to API", err)
              })
    }
    render() {
        // console.log(this.state.stripdata)
        return (
          <div className="App">
            <Header onQuery={1}/>
            {   
                (this.state.data === null) ? <div className="loading">Loading data...</div> : <Content onResult={this.state.stripdata}/>
            }
            <Footer />
          </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Content.jsx:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Result from './Result'

class Content extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        stripdata: this.props.onResult
      };
    }
    componentWillMount() {

    }
    render() {
        console.log("im an Content: " + this.state.stripdata)
        return (
          <div className="Content">
            <Result stripdata={ this.state.stripdata }/>
          </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Content;
```

Result.jsx:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PersonCard from './PersonCard'

class Result extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        stripdata: this.props.stripdata
      };
    }
    componentWillMount() {

    }

    render() {
        console.log("im the Result: " + this.state.stripdata)
        return (
          <div className="result">
            <PersonCard />  
          </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Result;
```

Please help. This is blocking my progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix the issue here:

```
<Header onQuery={1}/>
        {   
            (this.state.stripdata === null) ? <div className="loading">Loading data...</div> : <Content onResult={this.state.stripdata}/>
        }
```

You need to check properties in state with name `stripdata`.

And btw, fetch has to be performed in ComponentDidMount, see https://daveceddia.com/where-fetch-data-componentwillmount-vs-componentdidmount/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that, in your `Results`, you are only using the value from `props` once: in the constructor, where you set to state.

You should not set value in state from props. Instead, just use the props directly. Change `Result` to as following, then it will work proper:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PersonCard from './PersonCard'

class Result extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      // removed setting state from props.stripdata 
    }

    render() {
        console.log("im the Result: " + this.props.stripdata) // <-- using props!
        return (
          <div className="result">
            <PersonCard />  
          </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Result;
```

In general it is considered bad practice/antipattern to set state from props.